# Error on http requests from ionic iOS native to WP rest API (works on web view and DevApp)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, wordpress-rest-api

We are trying to issue http requests from our ionic app to a Wordpress server (REST API) and get the following error:
`{"_body":{"isTrusted":true},"status":0,"ok":false,"statusText":"","headers":{},"type":3,"url":null}`.

The requests are working fine when we use the web view or ionic DevApp and are failing on iOS devices.

What we did so far:

- We verified the requests work fine through the DevApp and the web view.
- We relaxed the cordova whitelist plugin (see our config.xml below).
- We verified CORS are enabled on our servers (see curl CORS check below)
- We checked there is no CORS preflight request issued from the iOS device when the request is blocked as we can see the GET request and no OPTIONS request on the server access log.
- Obviously there is connectivity from the device to the server as we can see the GET request.

If you have any suggestions, even if seem far fetched, we would very much like to hear them.

Thanks for the help!

**requesting code**

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

...

private requestData(path: String, params:Object = {}){
  return this.http.get( this.request.url + path, {
    params: {
      'consumer_key': this.conf.comm.appId,
      'consumer_secret': this.conf.comm.appSecret
    }
  })
  .map( (res: Response) => this.prepareResponse(res) )
  .catch( (res: Response) => this.catchError(res) );
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="app.c***r.***" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>***</name>
    <description>The ***</description>
    <author email="admin@c***r.app" href="https://c***r.app">***</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="localhost:8080" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        ...
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        ...
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="3.2.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.5" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~7.1.4" />
</widget>
```

**curl CORS check**

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 18.224.***.***...
* Connected to p***r.app (18.224.***.***) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
...
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /wp-json/wc/v2/products/categories?consumer_key=ck_3***2&consumer_secret=cs_0***b&per_page=100 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: p***r.app
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://localhost:8080
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 12 Apr 2019 14:44:43 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.31
< X-Robots-Tag: noindex
< Link: <https://p***r.app/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
< X-WP-Total: 98
< X-WP-TotalPages: 1
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
< Allow: GET
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Vary: Origin
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
<
```

Comment: What do you mean "failing" ?

Comment: We've got a response when testing the app through the web view and DevApp but not when we compiled it and tried it on a real device (in which case we got the error mentioned on the question). Anyway, we found the reason and are fixing it right now. Will update with answer when we are done.

Answer (score 8):

The problem was caused by ionic sending `ionic://localhost` as the origin when used as a compiled app. WP REST responds through [rest_send_cors_headers](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_send_cors_headers/), which passes the origin through `esc_url_raw` and rejects the url due to its protocol.

To fix this just add the protocol `ionic` to the allowed protocols list through the filter `kses_allowed_protocols`.

BTW, if you're from ionic and reading this, consider making the compiled apps behave as close as possible to the web view and DevApp, including origins sent to the servers.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue. Could you please clarify where I would locate the allowed protocol list, to add the ionic protocol? (I'm new to this)

Comment: Please get back to me when you can. This issue is so frustrating.

Comment: You need to subscribe to `kses_allowed_protocols` on WP and add `ionic` as an approved protocol. I'd advise you to google [CORS](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+cors) as well as [WP hooks](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+are+wp+hooks) if you are new to those subjects.

Comment: Thank you for the help! The links were very helpful and I've now resolved the issue.

Answer (score 8):

Here’s the code I used after seeing the helpful answers above. Posting in case others are looking for the same solution. This can go in functions.php in your theme or wherever’s convenient.

```
add_filter('kses_allowed_protocols', function($protocols) {
    $protocols[] = 'ionic';
    return $protocols;
});
```

Comment: $protocols[] = 'capacitor'; in case you on capacitor