# CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin iOS

Tags: angular, wordpress-rest-api, capacitor

I'm developing an iOS app in Angular/Ionic/Capacitor. The app works great on Android, but server calls are refused on iOS due to CORS.

The app uses a WordPress API which includes the following function;

```
function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```

I tried setting the server in capacitor.config.json, that didn't work.

Also tried the following in config.xml

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSAppTransportSecurity">
```

The config.xml already includes

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Still doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655100/error-on-http-requests-from-ionic-ios-native-to-wp-rest-api-works-on-web-view-a)

By adding

```
add_filter('kses_allowed_protocols', function($protocols) {
    $protocols[] = 'capacitor';
    return $protocols;
});
```